# Why is NPM not working on windows 10 after installing latest NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I installed the latest Node JS (64-bit) for Windows 10  (version 20H2, Build 19042.1348)

In an administrator powershell, when I type: >npm    I get the following:

============================================================================

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm
npm : TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
At line:1 char:1
+ npm
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (TypeError: Clas...tructor or null:String) [], Remo 
   teException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v10.17.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy
-agent\dist\agent.js:114:44)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> 
(C:\ProgramData\nvm\v10.17.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\index.js:5:33)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v10.17.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-
happen\lib\agent.js:161:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v10.17.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy
-agent\dist\agent.js:114:44)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> 
(C:\ProgramData\nvm\v10.17.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\index.js:5:33)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v10.17.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-
happen\lib\agent.js:161:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
```

============================================================================

Any ideas?

I've tried:
uninstalling reinstalling Node via the latest .msi,
and installing node via Chocolatey.

Comment: Seems you have nvm messing things up. Probably need to tell it to use the latest version?

Comment: Ok, I installed the latest NVM for windows 1.1.8 (I had 1.1.7), but npm is still giving the same error.

Comment: After a reboot, then running nvm install 17.1.0, my npm is now working without error!!  Ty!